# Decrypt and Forward

Tags: encryption

I have a Ubuntu machine running SSH, I need  to forward the incoming traffic to another machine over a secondary Ethernet adapter (IE eth1) after it has been properly encrypted:

something similar to the solution provided here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/638272/dnat-packet-after-decryption-of-ipsec

I thought of interrupting the encrypted traffic to the border router, however I'm doing this in a virtualised environment and I'd like to reduce the numbers of the devices.

Do you have a working solution to this?

Comment: This is more of a config/operational question and perhaps a custom script issue. Migrating to a more Linux operational site.

Comment: I can't really tell what the end goal is here. Are you looking for something like SSH port forwarding?

Comment: Hi Michael, does SSH port forwarding forward data after decryption?
I need to be able to read the data after decryption for further analysis, possibly at the destination.

Comment: Isn't this describing an ssh tunnel? Or you want to decrypt & read/copy the data on the intermediate machine, then send another copy on? Use a second ssh?

Answer (score 1):

At the end I had to settle down for a reverse proxy running haproxy,
This leaves a segment from the server to the proxy free of encryption. for further analysis.